# View Frame Changes On Hide/Show Navigation Bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

In My Application,

I have Navigation Controller with root view controller.

To show/hide navigation bar which works fine.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    BOOL navbarhide=[self.navigationController.navigationBar isHidden];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!navbarhide animated:YES];


}
```

Works good but,

When navigation bar is hidden then view frame changes.

When navigation bar is not hidden then view frame changes.

[image: When navigation bar is not hidden ..see the press button and view's origin is below the bar, I dont want like this I want it to stick at navigation bar's origin[at the top of the page]]

[image: It is fine view is at its original position when bar is hidden. I want view to be stick at this position and turn bar hide/show without changing the view's frame.]

Thanks in Advance...

Edit Setting set self.view.frame does not make any effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same problem. In my project, it is because the view is scroll view. If your view is a scroll view or table view, you can try this:

I add below code to the controller.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the frame of `self.view`. I don't use `setNavigationBarHidden:` to hidden the navigation bar, but directly change the frame of self.navigationController.navigationBar. In this way, `self.view.frame` won't change.

```
CGRect frame = (navBarhidden) ? CGRectMake(0, -24,self.view.bounds.size.width,44) :      CGRectMake(0, 20,self.view.bounds.size.width,44);
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = frame;
```

Comment: but that's leaves a black space in its old place.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem while displaying UIView fullscreen. Resizing frame worked for me. (Swift)

hiding navigationBar:

```
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = true
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= 64
    self.view.frame.size.height += 64.0
```

showing navigationBar again:

```
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = false
    self.view.frame.origin.y += 64
    self.view.frame.size.height -= 64.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is by default functionality which cannot be changed by you, but you change the position of the button by using following code

myButton.frame = CGRectMake(X, Y, Height, Width);

after hiding the navigation bar.

Comment: actually this is test code I want to implement it to my app...so if you can get..

Comment: When u click on the button then change the values of the myButton.

Change the values and try this.
I think you will got your solution.

Comment: Yes I can move the button, but in my real app I have many components so it is messy to move components!!!1

Comment: Ok.
So try in real application if u have any difficulty then ask me.

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help you

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
BOOL navbarhide=[self.navigationController.navigationBar isHidden];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!navbarhide animated:YES];
 if(navbarhide)
 self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480);
 else
  self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,44, 320, 480);
 }
```

Comment: this does not effect because navigation start hiding after you set the frame. and removes what you did.

Answer (score 0):

change the self.view.frame when you are showing and hiding the navigation bars

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Comment: Code only answers are improved with some explanation.